# Complementary subspaces, True/False question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

True or False?

$W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ are subspaces from the vectorspace $V$. If $W_1 ⊕ W_2 = V$ and $W_1 ⊕ W_3 = V$ , then
$W_2 = W_3$.

I actually had this smaller question asked on a exam and I said it was true but I was later told it was false. Can somebody explain to me why so I can intuitively see it in my head that it's indeed false. Only then I can come up with a counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of three planes intersecting in a line.

Comment: Take the $x$ axis for $W_1$ the $y$ axis for $W_2$ and the line $y=x$ for $W_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_2$ and $W_3$ are isomorphic, but might not be the same subspace.

One way to look at this is to first choose a basis $B$ of $W_1$. There are different ways of extending this basis to a basis of $W_1 \oplus W_2$, so the additional vectors added to $B$ might span different subspaces.

Another way is to imagine an automorphism $\alpha$ of $V$, (i.e. $\alpha:V \to V$ is an invertible linear map). Suppose that $W_1$ is an invariant subspace of $\alpha$. Then $W_1 \oplus \alpha (W_2)=V$ for all such $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed wrong ! You have for example that $$\mathbb R^2=\text{Span}\{(1,0)\}\oplus \text{Span}\{(0,1)\}=\text{Span}\{(1,0)\}\oplus \text{Span}\{(1,1)\},$$
but $$\text{Span}\{(1,1)\}\neq \text{Span}\{(0,1)\}.$$